Let $BAC$ be a triangle. What can be said about the limiting slope of BC when the $\angle A$ goes to $\pi$.
Question
Let $BAC$ be a triangle. Let a line $L$ of slope $m$ pass through the point $A (z,f(z))$ which is tangent of $f$ at the $x$ coordinate of $A$. Now assume $B$ and $C$ are moving such that $B$ corresponds to $(s,f(s))$ where $s \leq z$ and $C$ corresponds to $(t,f(t))$ where $t \geq z $ and $s, t$ move towards the $x$ coordinate of $A$. Thus, the following  condition is satisfied:
1.)  The slope of $BA$ and $CA$ tends to slope of $L$
2.) The line $L$ doesn't intersect any sides of triangle $BAC$
Then can we say "using geometry" that the slope of $BC$ tends to slope of $L$
Context
I want to prove the following using the above theorem.
Let $f$ be a function which is differentiable at $z$. This implies that $ \forall \epsilon > 0  \  \exists  \delta > 0 \ni \forall s,t \ \ \  \ni z-\delta < s \leq z \leq t < z+\delta \ \  \Bigg|\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}-f'(z)\Bigg| < \epsilon $
To me the geometry argument seems enough. But my friend said we have to show rigorously that the slope of the segment $BC$ goes to the slope of the line $L$.

The rigorous argument won't talk about slopes and triangles and moving points, it will start with the limit definition of the derivative. Separate note: I think statements and proofs are much better written as much as possible in English with logical notation kept to a minimum.

@EthanBolker So is the geometric argument enough?

Consider an isosceles triangle with $A$ as the vertex where $L$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC.$ If we just move points $B$ and $C$ perpendicularly toward the line, then the slopes of $BA$ and $CA$ should tend toward the slope of $L$ while $BC$ and $L$ remain perpendicular. Without further restriction this statement should be false

@Debu Enough for what? I haven't even tried to draw your picture. A correct one might provide a convincing argument for why the formal statement should be provable. It's not a proof, which can only follow step by step from the actual definitions.

The statement is blatantly false. What does $L$ have to do with the tangent line of a curve through $A$ and containing $B$ and $C$? Draw pictures.

And where does angle $\pi$ in the title come from? In the body you’ve said that both $B$ and $C$ approach the line $L$. Are you further requiring that they approach from opposite sides of $A$? That would make sense and then the counterexamples seem to disappear. Nevertheless, what is the differentiable function $f$ in your analytic set-up?

@TedShifrin Thanks for your input. could you see now. I have made it preciser.

OK, much better. Of course, you mean $s<z<t$ (no equality allowed). I would rephrase entirely by starting with the graph, but this is OK.  This is now in fact a standard exercise in analysis: Prove that $$\lim_{h,k\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k} = f'(x).$$ You have to do a bit of algebraic manipulation in the limit proof.

@TedShifrin I have actually two fold doubt: 1.) Is the geometric sketch clear enough to be valid proof or atleast almost a proof, I am saying it because the fact that BC's slope tends to the derivative $f'(z)$ seems to be trivial, but a person disagreed that this is not trivial enough.
2.) What's the trick of algebraic manipulation? I tried a lot, hence switched to this hand-wavy geommetric method.

The geometry argument is a hand-wave heuristic, not (to me) a complete proof, even though I am by nature fond of geometry. It is not trivial. Add and subtract $f(x)$ in the numerator and subtract $f’(x)$. Show that the resulting limit is $0$ by breaking it into two pieces.

@TedShifrin Actually I did manipulation till there, and each time I was stuck because of the denominator. It's not just $h$ and $k$ but $h+k$ so even after breaking the sum into two pieces, it wasn't exactly like the form $\frac{f(y+z)-f(y)}{z}$ due to the denominator.

Ah, so, as we added a “clever $0$” earlier, now you need to multiply by “clever $1$’s” …
